# "lerna changed" lists all packages

Tags: npm, package, yarnpkg, lerna

I've cloned a monorepo I was working on onto a new dev machine, all packages from the repo have been published already. But when I run `lerna changed` - it says "assuming all packages changed" and lists all the packages from the repo. And if I run `lerna publish from-package` - it correctly says that there's nothing to publish.

My `lerna.json`

```
{
  "packages": [
    "packages/*"
  ],
  "command": {
    "publish": {
      "registry": "https://npm.pkg.github.com/"
    }
  },
  "npmClient": "yarn",
  "useWorkspaces": true,
  "version": "independent"
}
```

Any idea why it's doing this and how I can make `changed` correctly detect only changed packages?

Answer (score 3):

I ended up using `lerna ls --since master` instead. Since all PRs in our case are done from other branches into master, comparing working branch to master seems to make sense.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem. This worked for me:

```
lerna publish ----include-merged-tags
```